# SocketDescriptor of QTcpSocket is -1

Tags: qt, tcp

I am designing server/clients system for my own. I create a class with extending from `QTcpServer` and define `QMap <ClientName, int> sockets` to handle connected clients. Clients can  connect to server when `sockets` map doesn't contains socket with same `ClientName` as new client. So, when new socket connects to server, I store client `Pair <ClientName, SocketDescriptor>` in qmap. With these explanation, I should remove client descriptor from qmap when client `disconnects` from server. So, I create slot `void disconnected()` and implement it as follow:

```
void MyServer::disconnected()
{
   QTcpSocket* socket = (QTcpSocket*) sender();
   ClientType socketType = ClientTypeNone;
   foreach(ClientType key, _sockets.keys())
   {
      if (sockets.value(key) == socket.socketDescriptor())
      {
         socketType = key;
         break;
      }
   }

   if (socketType != ClientTypeNone)
   {
      sockets.remove(socketType);
   }
}
```

But, `socket.socketDescriptor` is -1, while I've set it in below code:

```
void MyServer::inComingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
   QTcpSocket* socket = nextPendingConnection();
   connect(s, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead());
   connect(s, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected());
   socket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);
}
```

What was it wrong ?

Comment: I assume the fd is reset inside the socket to -1 as its now disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

This is the QT Assistant answer,maybe help,

```
qintptr QTcpServer::socketDescriptor() const
```

Returns the native socket descriptor the server uses to listen for incoming instructions, or **-1 if the server is not listening.**

If the server is using `QNetworkProxy`, the returned descriptor may not be usable with native socket functions.

Comment: OP asked the socket / client, not the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think your function inComingConnection should be renamed to incomingConnection to become a valid override one.

But why you're not let Qt setting the descriptor for you?
Accordingly to the Qt Documentation:

> `void QTcpServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)`
>
> ... The base implementation creates a QTcpSocket, **sets the socket
>   descriptor** and then stores the QTcpSocket in an internal list of
>   pending connections. Finally newConnection() is emitted. ...

so that you could simply use addPendingConnection instead:

```
void MyServer::addPendingConnection(QTcpSocket *s)
{
   QTcpServer::addPendingConnection(s);
   connect(s, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead());
   connect(s, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected());
}
```